# chart JS with scale range value

Tags: angular, charts

I'm trying to find a way to present a chart that has start value and end value so that it will be presented as a filled range Y1<->Y2.

each point can have different ranges. 
For each point I actually need to supply two values.

does chart JS support this kind of graph?

Please see attached the required graph.
[image: graph]
Thanks,
Tali